# Windows 11: Issues with opening a text file containing accented characters

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-excel, notepad++, notepad

I'm having some issues in the way in Windows 11 Pro is handling text files.  I live in a two language environment - English and French.

For several years I have been using a number of Excel VBA macros on Windows 10 Pro to create French-English content for my website. One particular case involves creating photo captions in both languages with the resulting text saved to a text file (filescripting object). Using Windows 10 I could open the text file with Notepad and the accented characters were preserved correctly and could be transferred (copy/paste) to HTML code for my website. In Windows 11 Pro this is not the case as in Notepad all accented characters are displayed as a block symbol which seems to copy (cntl-C) as a space.

In another case, from Microsoft Expresion Web 4 I'm doing a "Save As" to copy code from existing web pages for manual editing.  The resulting "Save As" file, when opened in Notepad, also has this problem, ie accented characters which were ok in the original are not displayed correctly.

I have found that I can open these files on Windows 11 with Notepad++ and correctly see the content.

So, it seems to me that Notepad (Windows 11 version) is not using the same character encoding system as was being used in Windows 10.

Is there another explanation and/or what can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Are you using a different font maybe? It may be the font does not have these characters.

Comment: For French and English, use text file in UTF-8. The first 3 bytes of the text file should be the UTF8-BOM: 0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF. The program which read the text file will correctly interpret UTF8 character codes for rendering. Without UTF8-BOM, it works also provided the program reading the file is clever enough to understand "strange" character code are actually UTF-8. If it is not clever enough, text will show strange characters. Of course, in any case, the software used for rendering must use a font having accented characters.

Comment: You can play with Notepad++ to create text files with or without UTF8-BOM. Using Notepad++: Menu -> Encoding -> UTF8 or Menu -> Encoding -> UTF8-BOM. You can use a tool such as "HxD Hex Editor" to see the text file dumped as hex character codes.

Comment: The fonts in both the Windows 10 and windows 11 Notepad are the same: Consolas.  However, in Windows 10 font tab there is an option for "Script" (Western selected) which is not there in Windows 11.

Comment: @fpiette
Yes, I agree that the encoding choice/default for Windows 11 Notepad is not recognizing that there are accented characters in the file.  But, it is not clear to me how to override that and to specify the encoding you have suggested (UTF8-BOM).

Comment: I don't know how you create the text file. All you need is to write the UTF8-BOM first then your text with accented letters in UTF8. Maybe you could ask a new question like "How to create an UTF8 text file using <your software tool here>" and of course show the code you are using.

Comment: @fpiette I detailed the source of the text files in my origianl question.  One was created by an Excel VBA macro using the filescripting object to create the file and the other was created by Microsoft Expression Web 4 using the FileSave as option.

Comment: Show Excel VBA macro source code so that we can test what you have.